# Giving a border to an HTML table row, <tr>

Tags: html, css, border, html-table

Is it possible to border a table row, `<tr>` in one go instead of giving a border to individual cells, `<td>` like,

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border: 1px;" rules="none">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 96px;">Column 1</th>
            <th style="width: 96px;">Column 2</th>
            <th style="width: 96px;">Column 3</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="border-left: thin solid; border-top: thin solid; border-bottom: thin solid;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-top: thin solid; border-bottom: thin solid;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-top: thin solid; border-bottom: thin solid; border-right: thin solid;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This gives a border around the given `<tr>` but it requires a border around individual cells.

Can we give a border to `<tr>` only in one go?

[→ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d73e7/)

Answer (score 178, accepted):

You can set `border` properties on a `tr` element, but according to the CSS 2.1 specification, such properties have no effect in the separated borders model, which tends to be the default in browsers. Ref.: 17.6.1 [The separated borders model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#separated-borders). (The *initial* value of `border-collapse` is `separate` according to CSS 2.1, and some browsers also set it as *default value* for `table`. The net effect anyway is that you get separated border on almost all browsers unless you explicitly specifi `collapse`.)

Thus, you need to use collapsing borders. Example:

```
<style>
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
tr:nth-child(3) { border: solid thin; }
</style>
```

Comment: @Robert Siemer While it is true that this puts a border around rows, it also requires "border-collapse: collapse".  Columns cannot be spaced using the cellpadding property in this manner.  The outline property used in csmckelvey's answer below provides for greater control over the look of the table and achieves exactly the same goal.  This should not be the accepted answer as it unnecessarily limits functionality to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 105):

Absolutely! Just use

```
<tr style="outline: thin solid">
```

on which ever row you like. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d73e7/7/).

Of course, as people have mentioned, you can do this via an id, or class, or some other means if you wish.

Comment: <tr> should be a container not an element so formatting his child through his style is not correct in terms of semantics, even if it works.

Comment: Google Chrome and Internet Explorer show a border around a `<tr>` but Mozilla Fire Fox doesn't display a border.

Comment: Try using `outline` instead of `border`. That should fix compatibility. I only have Chrome atm, so I can't test it.

Comment: Outline is not border.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela What are the main differences? If you use outline and no border, are there any visual differences? Also, if this is incorrect can you provide a correct solution?

Comment: Chrome 37 does not put a border on `tr` http://jsbin.com/mopuci/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @takendarkk outline do not work with `border-radius`

Comment: @tsh border-collapse: collapse doesn't work with cellpadding

Comment: A good suggestion, but in my case, I want to be able to set border-top and border-bottom.  `outline` does not seem to provide this functionality.

Comment: Outline is too close to the contents of the row, and padding does not work inside of outlines. Also, you can't show a bottom line this way.

Answer (score 19):

Yes. I updated my answer **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d73e7/2/)**

```css
table td {
    border-top: thin solid; 
    border-bottom: thin solid;
}

table td:first-child {
     border-left: thin solid;
}

table td:last-child {
     border-right: thin solid;
}
```

If you want to style only one `<tr>` you can do it with a class: **[Second DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d73e7/9/)**

Comment: It looks like Internet Explorer dislikes `last-child` (It does not seem to support).

Comment: @Tiny which IE version do you wish to support? Version 9+ supports first-child and last-child.

Comment: You are not styling <tr>, you’re styling <td>.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the box-shadow property on a tr element as a subtitute for a border. As a plus, any border-radius property on the same element will also apply to the box shadow.

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: This offers much more control over styling than `outline` does. Should be a higher answer.

Comment: Very good workaround

Comment: box-shadow-bottom: rgb(0, 0, 0) did not work for me to draw a line under a row.

Answer (score 8):

Make use of CSS classes:

```
tr.border{
    outline: thin solid;
}
```

and use it like:

```
<tr class="border">...</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

Left cell:

```css
style="border-style:solid;border-width: 1px 0px 1px 1px;"
```

midd cell(s):

```css
style="border-style:solid;border-width: 1px 0px 1px 0px;"
```

right cell:

```css
style="border-style:solid;border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0px;"
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border: 1px;" rules="none">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 96px;">Column 1</th>
            <th style="width: 96px;">Column 2</th>
            <th style="width: 96px;">Column 3</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="border-left: thin solid; border-top: thin solid; border-bottom: thin solid;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-top: thin solid; border-bottom: thin solid;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-top: thin solid; border-bottom: thin solid; border-right: thin solid;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you add comment to your answer and explain what did you changed?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (Border Just bottom of every row)

```
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 }
```

Comment: Works better, but removes all padding from the table.

Answer (score 0):

adding border-spacing: 0rem 0.5rem; creates a space for each cell (td, th) items on its bottom while leaving no space between the cells

```
    table.app-table{
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 0rem 0.5rem;
    }
    table.app-table thead tr.border-row the,
    table.app-table tbody tr.border-row td,
    table.app-table tbody tr.border-row th{
        border-top: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
        vertical-align: middle;
        white-space: nowrap;
        font-size: 0.875rem;
    }

    table.app-table thead tr.border-row th:first-child,
    table.app-table tbody tr.border-row td:first-child{
        border-left: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
    }

    table.app-table thead tr.border-row th:last-child,
    table.app-table tbody tr.border-row td:last-child{
        border-right: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

While the TR element doesn't seem to honor CSS, the TD element does. So you can set borders to draw lines and set padding to adjust position, just by applying CSS to TD elements. It works for an entire row if you apply the same CSS to all the TDs for that row.

Answer (score -7):

After fighting with this for a long time I have concluded that the spectacularly simple answer is to just fill the table with empty cells to pad out every row of the table to the same number of cells (taking colspan into account, obviously). With computer-generated HTML this is very simple to arrange, and avoids fighting with complex workarounds. Illustration follows:

```
<h3>Table borders belong to cells, and aren't present if there is no cell</h3>
<table style="border:1px solid red; width:100%; border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr style="border-top:1px solid darkblue;">
        <th>Col 1<th>Col 2<th>Col 3
    <tr style="border-top:1px solid darkblue;">
        <td>Col 1 only
    <tr style="border-top:1px solid darkblue;">
        <td colspan=2>Col 1 2 only
    <tr style="border-top:1px solid darkblue;">
        <td>1<td>2<td>3

</table>


<h3>Simple solution, artificially insert empty cells</h3>

<table style="border:1px solid red; width:100%; border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr style="border-top:1px solid darkblue;">
        <th>Col 1<th>Col 2<th>Col 3
    <tr style="border-top:1px solid darkblue;">
        <td>Col 1 only<td><td>
    <tr style="border-top:1px solid darkblue;">
        <td colspan=2>Col 1 2 only<td>
    <tr style="border-top:1px solid darkblue;">
        <td>1<td>2<td>3

</table>
```