# CSS not working in Chrome if I add it in the <style> element

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a simple table with styles applied via inline CSS, and it is working. But when I try to add the CSS to the document via the  element, it doesn't work in Chrome. I checked the W3Schools CSS tutorials, but couldn't find a solution.

My code is this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style type="text/css">
         tr {
         border: solid 1px black; 
         padding-left: 7px; 
         padding-right: 7px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table id="t01" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E4E5E0; margin-left: 40px;">
         <tr style="border: 1px solid black;">
            <th>Available<br>On</th>
            <th>Ids</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="border: solid 1px black; padding-left: 7px; padding-right: 7px;"><b>Phone</b></td>
            <td style="border: solid 1px black; padding-left: 7px; padding-right: 7px;"><b>9999999
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <br><br>
      <table id="t01" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E4E5E0; margin-left: 40px;">
         <tr style="border: 1px solid black;">
            <th style="border: solid 1px black; padding-left: 7px; padding-right: 7px;">Available<br>On</th>
            <th style="border: solid 1px black; padding-left: 7px; padding-right: 7px;">Ids</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="border: solid 1px black; padding-left: 7px; padding-right: 7px;"><b>Phone</b></td>
            <td style="border: solid 1px black; padding-left: 7px; padding-right: 7px;"><b>9999999
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FIDUIS25NER6

Out put:

[image]

Comment: You need not specify  type="text/css".Simple <style></style> would do.

Comment: Try clearing cache or open your webpage in private browsing probably your changes are not pritning

Comment: What exactly is “not working”? And why are you only showing us code that has inline styles applied _and_ uses a `style` element in the head?

Comment: Inspect the DOM and see whether you actually see that style tag there. Right click and go to Inspect and then find the Elements tab.

Comment: If everything properly set, you need to clear cache data in your web browser. This also happened to me when using chrome

Comment: Your styles for tr inside the css is wrong. What is this: `<tr style="border: 1px solid black;">` and this: `tr {border: solid 1px black; ` your styles in style tag for border will overwrite from inside the tr tag.

Answer (score 2):

Change your CSS to the following.  It has a typo.

```
<style>
     th {
     border: 1px solid black; 
     padding-left: 7px; 
     padding-right: 7px;
     }
</style>
```

If you want to add border to `tr` [visit this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872200/giving-a-border-to-an-html-table-row-tr)

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
border: solid 1px black;
```

to this:

```
border: 1px solid black;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
     th {
     border: solid 1px black; 
     padding-left: 7px; 
     padding-right: 7px;
     }
 </style>
```

Actually in your code your are giving border to `tr` which does not make sense [click here to know more.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872200/giving-a-border-to-an-html-table-row-tr)

So replace `tr` to `th` in your above code and it work.

[image: code pic]