# Border-bottom-width is not showing in table

Tags: html, css

My problem is that in CSS, inside a `table tr:nth-child(1)` rule, `border-bottom-width: 5px` is not working, but `background-color: gold` is.

Any ideas how to make `border-bottom-width: 5px` work?

This is my full code:

```css
table {
  border: 5px double #999;
  background-color: white;
  border-spacing: 5px 1em;
  empty-cells: hide;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

table th,
table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

table tr:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: gold;
  border-bottom-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>zľavové hodiny</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>zač./deň</th>
    <th>pondelok</th>
    <th>utorok</th>
    <th>streda</th>
    <th>štvrtok</th>
    <th>piatok</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>10:00</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="3">práčky, sušičky (-20%)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>12:00</th>
    <td colspan="2">mikrovlnné rúry (-25%)</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>vysávače (-30%)</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you’re using expanded borders (with the `border-spacing` property), the `tr` elements have no borders - it’s the `th`s (or potentially `td`s) inside them that do.

You just need to explicitly state that you want to apply the border to the cells within the selected `tr`, like this:

```css
table tr:nth-child(1) > th {
  background-color: gold;
  border-bottom-width: 5px;
}
```

Full snippet:

```css
table {
  border: 5px double #999;
  background-color: white;
  border-spacing: 5px 1em;
  empty-cells: hide;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

table th,
table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

table tr:nth-child(1) > th {
  background-color: gold;
  border-bottom-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>zľavové hodiny</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>zač./deň</th>
    <th>pondelok</th>
    <th>utorok</th>
    <th>streda</th>
    <th>štvrtok</th>
    <th>piatok</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>10:00</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="3">práčky, sušičky (-20%)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>12:00</th>
    <td colspan="2">mikrovlnné rúry (-25%)</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>vysávače (-30%)</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to adjust the border of an individual table row with CSS, you need to add `border-collapse: collapse;` to your `table` element. This will cause the rest of your styling to look different, however. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872200/giving-a-border-to-an-html-table-row-tr) has more information.

```css
table { 
border: 5px double #999;
background-color: white;
border-spacing: 5px 1em;
empty-cells: hide;
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

table th, table td { 
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 0.5em; 
 }
 
table tr:nth-child(1) { 
background-color: gold;
border-bottom: 15px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <caption>zľavové hodiny</caption>
 <tr>
  <th>zač./deň</th><th>pondelok</th><th>utorok</th><th>streda</th><th>štvrtok</th><th>piatok</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>10:00</th>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td colspan="3">práčky, sušičky (-20%)</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>12:00</th>
  <td colspan="2">mikrovlnné rúry (-25%)</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>vysávače (-30%)</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```