# Too thick frame of tables when using html2pdf

Tags: html, css

I use html2php to create a PDF document. Now I want to frame a table very thin. Unfortunately the frame gets too thick when I use 1px.

```html
<table style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <col width="700">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li>Lölölö #1</li>
                <li>Lölölö #2</li>              
                <li>Lölölö #3</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>           
</table>
```

Comment: why php tag here? check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872200/giving-a-border-to-an-html-table-row-tr

Comment: html2php -> html2pdf?

Comment: Sorry, I mean html2pdf.

Comment: I've tried that in the link before. Unfortunately, the frame is still displayed thicker than it should be. Could the error be html2pdf?

Comment: try this on the style: `border: 0.1px solid black;`