# Unable to apply border-top and border-bottom to the <tr> tag

Tags: html, css

I want to create a tic-tac-toe like grid structure using html and css. I am unable to apply top and bottom border to the second  tag. Can someone help with this?

```css
td{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.MiddleColoumn{
 border-left-style: solid;
 border-left-color: black;
 border-left-size: 2px;

 border-right-style: solid;
 border-right-color: black;
 border-right-size: 2px;
}
#MiddleRow{
 border-top: 2px solid black;
 border-color: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<head>

</head>
<table>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td class="MiddleColoumn"></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="MiddleRow">
   <td></td>
   <td class="MiddleColoumn"></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td class="MiddleColoumn"></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Giving a border to an HTML table row, <tr>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872200/giving-a-border-to-an-html-table-row-tr)

Comment: The reason why the usage of the `table` element is frowned upon is that it behaves in unexpected ways like that. I recommend using CSS Grid or, if you need more backwards compatability, Flexbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a perfect use case for **CSS Tables**, using:

- `display: table`
- `display: table-row`
- `display: table-cell`

**Working Example:**

```css
.table {
 display: table;
}

.row {
 display: table-row;
}

.cell {
 display: table-cell;
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
}

.row.middle .cell {
  border-top: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.cell.center {
  border-left: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-right: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="table">

  <div class="row top">
   <div class="cell left"></div>
   <div class="cell center"></div>
   <div class="cell right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row middle">
   <div class="cell left"></div>
   <div class="cell center"></div>
   <div class="cell right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row bottom">
   <div class="cell left"></div>
   <div class="cell center"></div>
   <div class="cell right"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you wont be able to add border to tr directly. Instead, style the td's. Something like this by changing your CSS.

```
#MiddleRow td{
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    border-color: 2px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

**css**

```
#MiddleRow .MiddleColoumn{
  border-top:2px solid black;
  border-bottom:2px solid black;
}
```