# How to add a horizontal line after and before table headers row in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, html-table

I am making a react app where I have to add a full width horizontal line after and before the table header rows,How do I add it here?

```
 return (
    <div>
      <table width="100%">
       <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Sem</th>
          <th>Time</th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
        {tasks.map((task, index) => (
          <Task key={index} task={task} onDelete={onDelete} />
        ))}
        
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};
```

here all the `<th>` fields are headers,I have to add a horizontal line before the header row and one after the header row.

Can someone help?
Thanks

Comment: Hi, Use border-top and border-bottom on the tr tag.

Comment: not working,no borders

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use border-top and border-bottom, but simply adding that to the `<tr>` class will not work according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872200/giving-a-border-to-an-html-table-row-tr) post, The `<tr>` element will not take borders by itself. You will need to add a border-collapse to the table.

The implementation for this is below:

```css
table { 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
tr:nth-child(1) { 
  border-top: 1px solid black; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Sem</th>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: I am getting the borders but the width is diff,Top one is thicker

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the `::before` and `::after` selectors on the outer `div` element. I added an `id` attribute to the `div`-element to make sure the css rules don't conflict with other elements.

```css
#table-container::after, #table-container::before {
  display: flex;
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="table-container">
   <table width="100%">
     <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Sem</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the `<hr>` tag? or you can try this `<tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">` Also Here, you can try `border-top` and `border-bottom` with `<th>` and `<tr>` also.

Answer (score 0):

Add `border-top` & `bottom` on `th`

```
tr th { 
  border-top: 1px solid black; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```css
table { 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
tr th { 
  border-top: 1px solid black; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Sem</th>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: why is the above border thinner than the below one?